# How to get initiator in DevTools?

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, devtools

I'm trying to extract the initiator information of visited pages to understand what caused a request. Is it possible to get the initiator information via an API that is presented in DevTools without opening the DevTools tab? I can't find any API about that. I really just want to visit a webpage and get this information without opening that window.

[Sample Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y77mT.png)